# How to intercept all view controller viewDidAppear events in the app in one place?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have a UITabBarController-based app and there's an additional bar  similar to the Music app's player that appears above the tab bar.

Now I want to automatically add insets to all top level view controllers (actually all top-level scroll views) so that content is never covered by my additional bar.

One obvious way is subclassing all scroll views, table views etc. and add insets. Another way would be to subclass UIViewController and use it everywhere throughout the app. None of which is a good option in an existing app with dozens of view controllers. Neither do I want to use method swizzling.

So I'm thinking, the tab bar controller could somehow intercept all view controller presentation events (viewDidAppear?) in the app and adjust their top-level scrollable views accordingly.

However, can't seem to find an easy way of intercepting those events. Any ideas? Or any other ways of how insets can be injected automatically everywhere?

Comment: did you try to    create subclass of uiview controller which be superclass of all of the view controller you have, like base view controller  and override viewdid appear method.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya did you actually read the question?

Comment: @mojuba you can create a new UIViewController with container view and embed your UITabBarController in it. and adjust the constraints of ContainerView to incorporate the additional bar

Comment: I think there's a need for more details about your structure, if your TabBarController has only child view controllers (not navigation controllers) it might be easier. Also I don't think you need to change the insets in viewDidAppear (unless you do something else in viewDidLoad/willAppear). The insets can be set before adding the controller to the tab bar, they are not influenced by auto-layout.

Comment: @mojuba Yes I have read the question. But what you are asking is shortcut method which might be problematic for your future updates in the app. it is better to got with long but safe way. which i suggest you but any how it is your call :)

Answer (score 3):

> How to intercept all view controller viewDidAppear events in the app in one place?

There's no way to do this, besides swizzling UIViewController's `viewDidAppear:`.

> Or any other ways of how insets can be injected automatically everywhere?

Just set the `additionalSafeAreaInsets` on your UITabBarController. Call `viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange` when the additional bar appears or disappears (if so).

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution however should be noted it's available on iOS11+, also if my tabbar + additional bar are translucent with blur effect then I'm going to lose the effect unfortunately.